# Python + Pandas : Update ONE column in csv based on another csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have two similar tables ("hist.csv") :

```
Historical :
id | url | url2 | url3 | Time
1    A      B      C      5
2    D      E      F      8
```

And ("new.csv") :

```
New :
id | url | url2 | url3 | Time
1    A      Z      K      9
2    G      H      I      11
```

I want to update the New.Time column with the Historical.Time value, if "url" columns match.
i.e. desired output here with url "A" updated :

```
New2 :
id | url | url2 | url3 | Time
1    A      Z      K      5
2    G      H      I      11
```

I tried the following :

```
Historical = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("hist.csv", index_col='id', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
New = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("new.csv", index_col='id', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')

for index, row in New.iterrows():
    New.loc[index,'Time']=Historical.loc[historical['url'] == row['url'],'Time']

New.to_csv("new2.csv", sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

Raising :

```
 ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

PS : I found this thread :
[Updating a DataFrame based on another DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027533/updating-a-dataframe-based-on-another-dataframe)
But it looks like the proposed solution with "merge" does not really fit my needs, as I have many columns ?

Comment: Are you sure there would only be one value with that url in the historical csv?

Comment: I may have several rows with "url" in Historical, but they will have the same Time value. In that case, I should consider the first occurence/match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic issue is that `Historical.loc[Historical['url'] == row['url'],'Time']` returns a Series (even if there is only one row or no row where the condition - `Historical['url'] == row['url']` -matches). Example -

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  3

In [16]: df.loc[df['A']==1,'B']
Out[16]:
0    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

And then you try to set this DataFrame into a single cell of your `New` dataframe, which is what is causing the issue.

Since in the comments you say -

> I may have several rows with "url" in Historical, but they will have the same Time value. In that case, I should consider the first occurence/match.

A quick fix for your code would be to check whether `row['url']` exists in the other DataFrame, and only if true, to get the value from it using -

```
for index, row in New.iterrows():
    if row['url'] in Historical['url'].values:
        row['Time']=Historical.loc[Historical['url'] == row['url'],'Time'].values[0]
```

Comment: Thank you Anand. However with this fix I am updating row['Time'], but I am not updating "New" dataframe, am I ?

Comment: `row` is rows from `New` , so you are updating `New` only.

Comment: I have trouble with the test :  "if row['url'] in Historical['url']:" which is always False. Do I need to have the same index in both tables ? Which is not my case..

Comment: Oh sorry, you need to check `row['url'] in Historical['url'].values` . The other one only checks indexes

Comment: I finally was able to make it work using :  New.loc[index,"Time']=Hist.loc[Hist['url'] == row['url'],'Time'].values[0]